# Expected conv2d_19_input to have 4 dimensions Error in CNN via Python

Tags: python, pandas, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a problem about solving dimension in prediction method of CNN.
Before defining train and test data based on image , I posed a CNN model.
After the process has been done, I fitted the model.
When I predict the value by using model, It throws an error here.

How can I fix it ?

Here are my code blocks shown below.

**My Keras Libraries**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

**Here is my CNN Model**

```
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters = 32, 
                             kernel_size=(3,3), 
                             data_format= "channels_last", 
                             input_shape=(64, 64, 3), 
                             activation="relu")
              )

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

**Fitting CNN to Images**

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path, 
                                                 target_size=(64, 64), 
                                                 batch_size=32, 
                                                 class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_path,
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
```

**Fit Model**

```
classifier.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=50,
        epochs=30,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=200)
```

**Prediction**

```
S = 64

directory = os.listdir(test_forged_path)
print(directory[3])

print("Path : ", test_forged_path + "/" + directory[3])

imgForged = cv2.imread(test_forged_path + "/" + directory[3])
plt.imshow(imgForged)

pred = classifier.predict(imgForged) # ERROR
print("Probability of Forged Signature : ", "%.2f".format(pred))
```

**The Error :**

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_19_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (270, 660, 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `predict` method is missing the batch dimension from your input. Modify your prediction like so:

```
import numpy as np <--- import numpy

S = 64

directory = os.listdir(test_forged_path)
print(directory[3])

print("Path : ", test_forged_path + "/" + directory[3])

imgForged = cv2.imread(test_forged_path + "/" + directory[3])
plt.imshow(imgForged)

pred = classifier.predict(np.expand_dims(imgForged,0)) # <-- add new axis to the front, shape will be (1, 270, 660, 3)
print("Probability of Forged Signature : ", "%.2f".format(pred))
```

Comment: I wrong added tensorflow tag to the part. I used keras

Comment: What keras backend do you use? If you do not want to use tf (even though keras is included), then use `np.expand_dims(imgForged, 0)` instead. Tell me if this works, so that I can update my answer.

Comment: I editted my post to show keras libraries. Where do I use the code you said?

Comment: Updated my answer to use numpy instead of tensorflow.

Comment: I tried to use your code but it still throws an error. `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_19_input to have shape (64, 64, 3) but got array with shape (270, 660, 3) `

Comment: That is because the test image has different shape compared to the expected shape. You created your model to expect (64, 64, 3) (`classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters = 32, kernel_size=(3,3), data_format= "channels_last",  input_shape=(64, 64, 3), activation="relu") )`. Make sure your test data has the same shape.

Comment: My train data shape is (270, 660, 3) while test part is (163, 600, 3) . How can I define `input_shape`